# How to suppress scientific notation in Pig Output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

This is probably going to be a quick question but I tried googling to no avail. Basically I have an output in one of my output columns that is sometimes turning into scientific notation.

Example is this 3.9E-4. However, if the number is big enough, it keeps it as a floating point, like this 0.08544751199999999.

How do i suppress the scientific notation?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this with Pig Latin.  To solve a similar problem, I wrote myself a UDF that is just a wrapper for [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class SPRINTF extends EvalFunc<String> {

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input.size() != 2) { return null; }

        String output = null;
        try {
            String format = (String) input.get(0);
            String value = input.get(1).toString();

            switch (format.charAt(format.length()-1)) {
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
            case 's':
            case 'S':
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                output = String.format(format, value);
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'o':
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                output = String.format(format, Integer.parseInt(value));
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'f':
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                output = String.format(format, Double.parseDouble(value));
                break;
            }

            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) { return null; }
    }

}
```

Could certainly be improved upon, but it should give you an idea of how to begin.